# Request.Params for getting the values from the forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question. I don't know a lot when it comes to ASP. So here it goes:

Assume I have textbox1, textbox2 and listbox1.

in class a:
I create a User class like this:

`User user_a = new User();`

and instantiate the properties like this:

```
user_a.firstName = textbox1.text;
user_a.lastName = textbox2.text;
foreach (string groups in listbox1.items){
    user_a.groups.add(groups.toString());
}
```

There. That's just some rough example

Now how do I get the values of class A to class B?

It goes like:

```
User user_b = new User();
user_b.firstName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["textbox1"];
user_b.lastName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["textbox2"];
foreach (string groups in HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["listbox1"].items){
    user_b.groups.add(groups.toString());
}
```

The instructions say to use the HttpContext for getting the values from the forms. But it didn't tell me how to use it properly.

I'm highly sure that this isn't working even if I haven't tested it yet at run time (because I can't just yet... My co-workers are still fixing the main webpage and I was tasked to fix this one for the time being)

Comment: params you are specifying must be name attribute , can u please check this elements have input tag with name textbox1,textbox2 and so...

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" CssClass="inputText"></asp:TextBox>` is it the ID part? it doesn't have a Name and I am not allowed to modify those parts.

Comment: Is this Webfors or MVC?

Comment: look like asp.net webforms

Comment: I'm not so sure but I think it's Webforms cause I didn't saw anything mentioning MVC in the code.

Comment: @Don it should be the ID then; `txtUserName`. If you use the developer tools in Firefox or Chrome and inspect the network traffic, you will be able to see all of the parameters being passed, regardless if they are of GET or POST varieties, along with the cookies.